# Dictionary in Python from keyboard

Tags: python

I have a task in which I have to create a dictionary from the keyboard. Someone has to type two elements separated with comma (number, name) and starting from an empty dictionary I want to save every number and name. For example:

```
dic={}
#I type: 31, John
dic = {31:'John'}
#I type: 122, George
dic ={31:'John', 122:'George'}
```

and so on...

Notice that I have to convert the first number input into an integer.

I have a code so far at which dic takes the first input but replace the second input to the first so the results are:

```
dic={}
#I type 31, John
dic = {31:'John'}
#I type 122, George
dic ={122:'George'}
```

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    dic={}
    am, name=input('ΑΜ, Name: ').split(',')
    if am =='q':
        print('End')
        break
    else:
        AM = int(am)
        dic[AM]=name

    print(dic)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Move `dic={}` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
dic={}
while True:
    am, name=input('ΑΜ, Name: ').split(',')
    if am =='q':
        print('End')
        break
    else:
        AM = int(am)
        dic[AM]=name
    print(dic)
```

Comment: Yes it is! I have another question but this is not about the topic here but it is in the same code. May i ask here?

Comment: @Giannis If you have a new question, please ask it in a fresh question. You can link it to this question if you think it will be helpful.